# Containerd: Equivalent of docker inspect in containerd

Tags: docker, containerd

What is the equivalent of `docker inspect` in containerd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the container in containerd by using `info` in containerd.

First list out the containers that you are looking to inspect

`ctr --namespace k8s.io containers ls`

Containerd has namespaces https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/master/README.md#namespaces , so use --namespaces flag or ns flag, Above `k8s.io` is namespace

After getting the list of containers , you can get info about a particular container that you want using below command

syntax:

```
ctr --namespace <namespace_name> containers info <container_id>
```

ex :

```
ctr --namespace k8s.io containers info 85ed1aeb518ff57f6cc5b80c599f0c4bfcc8e944f842c98aeed5ffceaa5e6aaa
```